# Operator overloading as extension function

Tags: kotlin

In my game I have two players and so I defined a typealias of pair that should indicate that I have two things of the same type and `.first` belongs to player one and `.second` belongs to player two:

```
typealias PlayerPair<A> = Pair<A, A>
```

Also I have defined this enum class

```
enum class PlayerNumber {
    One,
    Two
}
```

Now i would like to add an operator (as extension function) to access the elements like this

```
myPair[Player.One]
```

That is my approch but it doesn't work

```
operator fun PlayerPair.get(i: PlayerNumber) = when (i) {
    PlayerNumber.One -> PlayerPair.first
    PlayerNumber.Two -> PlayerPair.sexond
}
```

Adding an else Branch removes one error, but I don't understand why it is necessary.

The other error is 'One type argument expected for typealias PlayerPair = Pair'.

But I can't figure out what this means in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic `get` function, you just have to specify a type parameter, and that you're extending a `PlayerPair<T>`:

```
operator fun <T> PlayerPair<T>.get(i: PlayerNumber): T = when (i) {
    PlayerNumber.One -> this.first
    PlayerNumber.Two -> this.second
}
```

Inside the operator, you can refer to the instance of `PlayerPair<T>` as `this`, which you can also use implicitly:

```
operator fun <T> PlayerPair<T>.get(i: PlayerNumber): T = when (i) {
    PlayerNumber.One -> first
    PlayerNumber.Two -> second
}
```

Comment: Having a generic type parameter is what I want. I only want to Use PlayerNumber for accessing purposes. So that means I have to have an overload for each type I use and can not have an generic overload?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the code in your question. I've updated my answer, hope I got it right now.

Comment: Thats it. Great! Thank you!